# Что быстрее сходить в базу и достать нужный объект или на более высоком уровне получить его?

Tags: postgresql, spring, mvc, hibernate, jpa

Использую Spring, Postgres, JPA и паттерн MVC. Я вот думаю, если кешировать коллекцию обьектов 100-200(7-10 полей), на уровне репозитория и потом возиться с ней на уровне сервисов, выполнять фильтрацию поиск и все остальное. Или же лучше для получения новой пачки объектов, в зависимости от параметров поиска, ходить в базу и пусть она выдает то что нужно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычное правило в таких случаях это не делать преоптимизацию. Я бы посоветовал пока не заморачиваться с создание кеша, если выяснится что работает медленно тогда подумать как оптимизировать. Если вы используете hibernate то можно сначала настроить кеш второго уровня.